# PHP's $_SERVER: QUERY_STRING

Tags: php

on http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php, it says

"
'QUERY_STRING'
The query string, if any, via which the page was accessed.
"

I've been having trouble comprehending that. As I understand it, the query string is simply there as input to the page. The script which the URL addresses uses the query string to do its work and generate whatever appropriate response it is designed to do.

I could understand, however, how that response (i.e. the webpage the script sends back) is said to be gotten via the query string, since the values in the query string were used to formulate it.. , but not the initial script that processed it.

It's a semantics issue.. appreciate your explanations.

Comment: You're thinking strictly in PHP. Think HTML.

Answer (score 1):

What you say has some truth, but you should stop thinking fixed in terms of "a script" or "a file" that is addressed. What *is* addressed is a page or an object from the point of view of the http protocol. It is irrelevant how or by what that was created. From *that* point of view the description is precise, since only the URL *including* the query string references the exact page or object the request results in.

A simple example where "the page" and "the script" creating the page are *not* closely coupled together are rewriting rules or routing scripts. in such examples the resulting page or object can be totally different depending on the content of the query string, although the URL itself is identical.

Comment: I just felt weird about it occurring there in the manual where I naturally assumed code context and programmer point of view, so I thought I might missing something.., whatever. Thanks for your insight (-: